# ListboxItem Storyboard Animation

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, animation, listbox

I have a `Listbox` that is declared with this:

```
    <ListBox Height="694" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="listBox1"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" />
```

`ListBoxItemStyle1` is a simple style to which I've added a `Storyboard`. My question is, how can I play this storyboard when the user selects the item? I want the selected`ListBoxItem` to animate but can't seem to access the Storyboard (called `sb`) from the code-behind as the compiler claims it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by putting an [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) in your Style. Not knowing your specific XAML, here's a generalized example:

```xml
<Style ... >
  <!--[etc...]-->
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selected">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard ...
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```